# How to use Hidden fields in HTML5 asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 asp.net application(vb.net project)

```
<table>
<tr><td>Billable item</td><td>@Html.DropDownList("RteBillableItem")    </td><td>Quantity</td><td>@Html.TextBox("Quantity")</td></tr>
<tr><td>Doctor Fee</td><td>@Html.TextBox("DoctorFee")</td><td>Hospital Fee</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("HospitalFee")</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="AddItem" value="Add Item" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

As seen in the image, i will be selecting an item from the drop down list, enter some data in the text boxes, and click on the button "Add Item", the form will do a post back.

The code in post back controller is :

```
HttpPost()
Function Index(ByVal Collection As FormCollection, ByVal Hidden As HiddenField) As ActionResult
  Dim Test As New TestModel
  Test.Update(CodeFactory(item), CInt(Collection("Quantity")),CInt(Collection("DoctorFee")), CInt(Collection("HospitalFee"))) 
  //This will add the Item in a dictionary which i have used in my ModelTest
  Return View(Test)
End Function
```

After adding the Item into my dictionary, i will send this model to "View", where i have to list the values in a table, picking the values from Dictionary of TestModel. The code for listing the values in View is:

```
@For Each item In Model
Dim currentItem = item
@<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.BillableItemId)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.BillableItemName)
</td>
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.OpBillId}) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = currentItem.OpBillId}) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = currentItem.OpBillId})
</td>
</tr>
next
</table>
```

But the thing is , whenever i do a post back, all the previous data which i have added in the dictionary of TestModel is lost. I know that i am re-initializing my Test object of the model, TestModel.

I think i have to use Hidden fields, to retain the old data of TestModel, even after PostBack.
But i do not know how to do it, please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing as Html.TextBox but you use Html.Hidden instead  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hidden(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks for your reply. Can i return the complete Model(which i have got from Controller after PostBack), back to Controller from View using Hidden Function like the one below? @Html.Hidden("Model", Model) And if this method is correct, How can i access this Hidden Model in controller?? –  Mayur 8 mins ago